# Bash shell, associative array empty after piping

Tags: bash, shell

*Bash 4.3.30*

Suppose you have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A map

f() {
    map[x]=a
    map[y]=b
}

g() {
    for k in "${!map[@]}"
    do
        echo "$k --> ${map[$k]}"
    done
}

f
g
```

This outputs

```
x --> a
y --> b
```

If I change the above mentioned program to `f | g` it outputs nothing.

I supposed declaring the associative array in global scope would allow me to access its values anytime and anywhere I wanted. I've read about strange problems with pipeline and scope but I've been unable to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you declare the variable doesn't matter. `f` runs in a separate process because it is in a pipeline, so any changes that `f` makes to `map` are isolated to *that* process. The fix in this case is easy; `f` doesn't produce any output, so there is no reason to use a pipe to connect it to `g`. Simply run `f`, *then* `g`.

```
f; g
```

Comment: What if I had to use `cat file.txt | f; g` because `f` needed some input? `g` in that case outputs nothing.

Comment: Well, for one, use `f < file.txt` not `cat`, but in general, you can either use the `lastpipe` option so that the *last* command in a pipeline executes in the current process (`shopt -s lastpipe; somecommand | f; g`), or use process substitution instead of a pipe (`f < <(somecommand); g`).